# R: calculating the probability of drawing at least 1 red marble

Tags: r, probability

Suppose my population has n marbles, and only 1% of them are red. In a sample of 30 draws, what's the probability that I draw at least 1 red marble?

I know that P(at least 1 red marble) = 1 - P(no red marbles)

I wrote a function in R

```
pMarble = function(n){
   1-(choose(n-ceiling(0.01*n), 30)/choose(n, 30))
}
```

The function takes in 1 parameter, the number of marbles in the population, and I use an sapply to iterate over the different values of n

```
n = 100:1000
toplot = sapply(n, pMarble)
plot(n, toplot)
```

[image]

Why is the plot discontinuous? I thought it would just be a decreasing, continuous function. As the total number of marbles increases, given that I'm only drawing 30 marbles, then the probability of drawing at least 1 red marble (present in the population at 1% frequency) would be monotonically decreasing? Why am I seeing discontinuities?

Comment: Hint: How can you have a population of greater than 100 but less than 200 marbles of which exactly 1% are red?

Comment: If the proportion always stays the same, then the graph should be a flat line at `1 - pbinom(0, 30, 0.01)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose my population has n marbles, and only 1% of them are red. In a sample of 30 draws, what's the probability that I draw at least 1 red marble?

You're right that the probability of at least 1 red marble is `1-Pr(no marbles)`; for a binomial, it's actually the case that (since the individual marble-selections within a draw are independent) that the probability of no marbles in 30 draws of `n` marbles is the same as the probability of no marbles in a single draw of `30n` marbles ... so we have `1-(1-p)^(30n)`.

```
p <- 0.01
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
curve(1-(1-p)^(30*x),from=0,to=100,
      xlab="Number of 30-marble draws",ylab="prob(>0 marbles)")
```

[image]

Let's test this empirically for a single case:

```
(1-(1-p)^(30*3))  ## 3 draws, 0.595
set.seed(101)
mean(replicate(100000,
          any(rbinom(3,prob=0.01,size=30)>0)))
## 0.59717
```

Comment: What if I'm drawing without replacement? In that case I wouldn't have a binomial distribution, correct?